# Replace Data With Key on 2 table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My question in kind of replace with key in SQL Server. Can anyone give me a query to do this?

Thanks for your answers!

`Table1`:

```
    ID | Code | Des | more columns
    ---+------+-----+-------------
    1  | 100  | a   | ...
    2  | 200  | b   | ...
    3  | 300  |data3| ...
```

`Table2`:

```
    ID | Code | Des 
    ---+------+------
    1  | 100  | data1   
    2  | 200  | data2
```

The result must be this:

```
    ID | Code | Des | more columns
    ---+------+-----+-------------
    1  | 100  |data1| ...
    2  | 200  |data2| ...
    3  | 300  |data3| ...
```

Comment: Hint:  `inner join`.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. The column 'Des' within the result should it report the corresponding value within the second table?

Comment: @RobertKock  if code common in 2 table , value of Des is from table 2 but if code not common in 2 table , value of Des is from table 1

Comment: Add ID = 4 to table2, and have different code values. (Or are code the join columns?)

Comment: @jarlh yea table 2 is kind of reformation table , where the Desc in table 2 must replace in table 1 where t1.Code=t2.Code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a `LEFT JOIN`, if there are no table2.Des value, take table1.Des instead:

```
select t1.ID, t1.Code, coalesce(t2.Des, t1.Des), t1.more Column
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.code = t2.code
```

Or, perhaps you want this:

```
select * from table2
union all
select * from table1 t1
where not exists (select 1 from table2 t2
                  where t2.code = t1.code)
```

I.e. return table2 rows, and if a code is in table1 but not in table2, also return that row.

Comment: Should be `coalesce(t2.Des, t1.Des)` instead of `coalesce(t2.Des, t2.Des)`

Comment: @hadi.k, just curious, which one did you chose?

Answer (score 2):

Use `JOIN`.

**Query**

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Code, 
CASE WHEN t1.Des LIKE 'data%' THEN t1.Des ELSE t2.Des END AS Des
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT          Table1.ID,
                Table1.Code,
                ISNULL(Table2.Des, Table2.Des) AS Des
FROM            Table1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2
             ON Table1.Code = Table2.Code;
```

You said "if code common in 2 table" so join on the code and not on the ID

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you want all results from Table1 but to use the value in 'Des' when it's available from Table2? You'd want to do something like this;

```
SELECT a.ID
    ,b.Code
    ,ISNULL(b.Des,a.Des) AS Des
FROM Table1 a
LEFT JOIN Table2 b ON a.ID = b.ID
```